# Ionic Slide React Content Is All On One Line

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ion-slides

I am trying to create a view with multiple slides. However, the components on the same slide render on just one line as opposed to the title above the button. Could someone help me fix this? My slides code is:

```
const ExploreContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <IonContent>
      <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOpts}>
        <IonSlide>
          <IonTitle size="large"> Slide 1 Title</IonTitle>
          <IonButton color="primary">Get Started</IonButton>
        </IonSlide>
        <IonSlide>
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </IonSlide>
        <IonSlide>
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        </IonSlide>
      </IonSlides>
    </IonContent>
  );
};
```

The display I'm getting is:

[image]

Comment: i dont see an error here?

Comment: @AaronSaunders could you explain why the components render in 1 line as opposed to below eachother?

Comment: what components are you talking about? I think you need to take a second look at the code and also be specific about what you are expecting to see

Comment: @AaronSaunders the title and the button render on the same line as opposed to the title being on one line and then the button under it. Is that the default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ion components must be wrapped in a `<div>`

The correct slide syntax should read:

```
   <IonSlide>
      <div><IonTitle size="large"> Slide 1 Title</IonTitle></div>
      <IonButton color="primary">Get Started</IonButton>
    </IonSlide>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IonSlide>
   <IonToolbar>
      <IonTitle size="large"> Slide 1 Title</IonTitle>
   </IonToolbar>
   <IonButton color="primary">Get Started</IonButton>
</IonSlide>
```

Comment: That still renders the title and button on one line. It looks like the slide itself doesn't expand to fill the entire IonContent container. Is there a way I can make sure it automatically does this?

Comment: wrap it in a <div>